# Can any body tell me why i m getting Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_ MALFORMED

Tags: android, android-manifest, unity-game-engine

I m working on a plugin for unity3d using java. i dont know why i suddenly get 
**Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_ MALFORMED** when i m trying to install in my android device.
I have made android build in Unity.

**I have cooked my jar with AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.mypack.test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" ></uses-sdk>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name=".TestActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**And in Unity3D my AndroidManifest.xml is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity3d.player" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">

  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"  android:normalScreens="true"  android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"></uses-sdk>  
    <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name"  android:debuggable="true">

      <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity"  android:label="@string/app_name"  android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
      </activity>

      <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
          <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
          <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
      </activity>

      <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
      </activity>

      <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
      </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I don't know why is this error coming. But i wrote *AndroidManifest.xml* again manually line by line & suddenly it starts working.

But couldn't figure out, why above files were not working..